# Multiple Folder Organising and Referencing CSS

Tags: css, image, background, directory

OK so I am Trying To Organize a file directory for a website. It looks like this.

```
 - My Blog Site
   - HTML-CSS-DOCUMENTS
     - CSS-MAIN.css
   - BACKGROUND-IMAGES
     - Background.png
```

But in the CSS document I cant seem to get it to use the image.

Here is the code I have been using

```
background-image:url("My Blog Site\BACKGROUND-IMAGES\Background.png");
```

Can someone please fix it or tell me what I'm doing wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use in your CSS:

```
background-image: url('../BACKGROUND-IMAGES/Background.png');
```

You go back one directory using the ../ and then link from that directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go back in the path and get your image. something like this:

```
background-image: url('../BACKGROUND-IMAGES/Background.png');
```

Here `../` means going one step back in the path. And use `/` instead of `\`.

Comment: Though they'd only go back one and not need the My Blog Site, if you used ./ then including My Blog Site is okay.

Comment: @RyanMcDonough yes you are right (I noticed now). Even not going one step back, it doesn't require. I am confused why OP mentioned so in his/her post.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
background:url('http://mywebsite.com/background-images/background.png');
```